# C# Setting cursor position - different results with WinForms and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have a strange problem. I am trying to set the cursor position with WPF. So far so good. The problem is the following:

On my computer screen (1920x1080, 100% windows scaling) everything works fine, but on my surface laptop (3000x2000, 200% windows scaling) I have run into some problems. Because of the scaling factor the "new resolution" is 1500x1000 (because of the 200% every pixel is "twice as big").

When I set the cursor to 750, 500 with WinForms the cursor appears in the exact middle of the screen but when I set the cursor position to the same point with WPF the cursor appears in the upper left section.

So apparently WinForms uses the resolution 1500x1000 and WPF uses the resolution 3000x2000 when setting the cursor position...

Why are they using different resolutions here? This doesn't make sense to me. Because when I am reading the ScreenWidth and Height with

```
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width // and Height, WinForms
```

and

```
System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth // and Heigth,  WPF
```

both are showing 1500x1000.

Can anyone help me? Maybe it is just a WPF/WinForms difference?

Code to set cursor:

```
Cursor.Position = p; // with imported System.Windows.Forms;

// or (tryed both)

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);
SetCursorPos(p.X, p.Y);
```

First post so please don't kill me!

Comment: Try calling `[DllImport("user32.dll")]private static extern bool SetProcessDPIAware();` from startup and see if it solves your issue.

Comment: To be clear, you are using the same `SetCursorPos` method in your WPF and WinForms apps, and calling it with the same argument values, but you are seeing different results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert in this topic, but maybe:

`WPF` uses vector graphics to render things, and has a native support for scaling. If you change font size in Windows to `200%`, every `WPF` application will be `2x` bigger.

But in `WinForms`, if you didn't write your application correctly, scaling can ruin your `UI`.

To avoid this, if you run `WinForms` app (in Windows 10) it will just use `100%` font size and it will stretch rendered image to `200%` size. So you can see for example blurry text. If image is stretched - screen coordinates must be stretched too.

But that's just my guess, I'm not an expert at this.

Comment: Sounds plausible for why `SetCursorPos` seems to apply logical pixels in OP's WinForms app but device pixels in the WPF app: there may be a compatibility layer feeding the WinForms app altered display metrics.

Comment: I guess this is the "problem". I also tried calling the SetProcessDPIAware() function but it did not work. So I guess I'll have to find a workaround or another calculation for the right screen coordinates. Thanks.